# South Africa ID number validation

Tags: angular

I've researched this but none of the code I use seems to work. South African ID numbers contain the date of birth and gender. All I want is it to pull in that information and verify it when their ID number is entered into an input field,  in angular

I have tried using the javascript code that I currently have just modified it to be in typescript. Im not getting any errors but it's not validating at all.

```
ts


 this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  confirm: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
};
      validateRSAidnumber(idnumber) {
        console.log('idnumber', idnumber);
    
        let invalid = 0;
    
        // check that value submitted is a number
        if (isNaN(idnumber)) {
          invalid++;
        }
    
        // check length of 13 digits
        if (idnumber.length !== 13) {
          invalid++;
        }
    
        // check that YYMMDD group is a valid date
        const yy = idnumber.substring(0, 2);
        const mm = idnumber.substring(2, 4);
        const dd = idnumber.substring(4, 6);
    
        const dob = new Date(yy, (mm - 1), dd);
    
        // check values - add one to month because Date() uses 0-11 for months
        if (!(((dob.getFullYear() + '').substring(2, 4) === yy) && (dob.getMonth() === mm - 1) && (dob.getDate() === dd))) {
          invalid++;
        }
    
        // evaluate GSSS group for gender and sequence 
        const gender = parseInt(idnumber.substring(6, 10), 10) > 5000 ? 'M' : 'F';
    
        // ensure third to last digit is a 1 or a 0
        if (idnumber.substring(10, 11) > 1) {
          invalid++;
        }
    
        // ensure second to last digit is a 8 or a 9
        if (idnumber.substring(11, 12) < 8) {
          invalid++;
        }
    
        // calculate check bit (Z) using the Luhn algorithm
        let ncheck = 0;
        let beven = false;
    
        for (let c = idnumber.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
          const cdigit = idnumber.charAt(c);
          let ndigit = parseInt(cdigit, 10);
    
          if (beven) {
            if ((ndigit *= 2) > 9) ndigit -= 9;
          }
    
          ncheck += ndigit;
          beven = !beven;
        }
    
        if ((ncheck % 10) !== 0) {
          invalid++;
        }
    
        return !invalid;
      }
    
    
      // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
      get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }
      get isEmailMismatch() { return this.registerForm.getError('emailMismatch'); }
    
      onSubmit() {
        console.log('buttoj');
        this.submitted = true;
   
        this.userService.user.user.email = this.email;
        this.userService.user.user.first_name = this.firstName;
        this.userService.user.user.last_name = this.lastName;
        this.userService.user.user.id_number = this.idNumber;
        this.userService.user.user.password = this.password;
        this.userService.user.user.phone = '0' + this.contactNumber.toString();
        this.userService.user.user.id_number = this.idNumber.toString();
        this.registerUser();
        this.validateRSAidnumber(this.idNumber);

}
```

Comment: Add some example data please.

Comment: i have a simple input filed and im trying to validate an sa ID number in angular

Comment: this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    
      idNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      confirm: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      contactNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
    },
      {
        validator: (form: FormGroup) => form.get('email').value !== form.get('confirm').value ? { emailMismatch: true } : null,

      },

Comment: im pretty new to angular so im trying to figure this out

Comment: <div class="form-group"><input [(ngModel)]="idNumber" type="number" formControlName="idNumber" id="idnumber digit-only-with-max-length"
 type="text"
            digitOnly
            maxlength="25"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.idNumber.errors }"
            placeholder="Id number (18 yaras or older and only South Africa IDs allowed)"
            digitOnly
          />

          <div *ngIf="submitted && f.idNumber.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.idNumber.errors.required">ID number required</div>
          </div>
        </div>

Comment: @thabangNkosi please don't use comments for code - you can update your question, including addition of example data requested.

Answer (score 0):

Information stored in the South African ID number(e.g 8801235111088):

- Digits 1 and 2 = year of birth (e.g 1988)
- Digits 3 and 4 = month of birth (e.g 01/January)
- Digits 5 and 6 = day of birth (e.g 23rd day)
- Digits 7 to 10 are used to define gender (Female = 0 to 4999; Male = 5000 to 9999) (e.g 5111 = Male)
- Digit 11 is used to classify your citizenship (SA citizen = 0; Non-SA citizen = 1)
- Digit 12 was used until the 1980's to classify race
- Digit 13 The last is used as a checksum to determine if the ID number is valid

Here is Python script to extract the info from any South African ID number:

```
Id = str(input("Please enter your South African Identity Number(ID): "))
#Id = "8801235111088"

#Date of birth
year = int(Id[0:2])
month = Id[2:4]
day = Id[4:6]

if year >= 50:
    print("Date of birth is: ", day, month, "19" + str(year) )
if year < 50:
    print("Date of birth is: " , day, month, "20" + str(year))

#gender
gender = int(Id[6:10])
if 0000 <= gender <= 4999:
    print("Gender is : female")
if 5000 <= gender <= 9999:
    print("Gender is: male")


#Citizen status
citizen = int(Id[10])
if citizen == 0:
    print("You are a South African citizen")
if citizen == 1:
    print("You are not a South African citizen")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an id validation service in my angular form validation. You could use it anywhere though.
It has been working well in my application for some time now.

*idValidation.service.ts*

```
export class IdValidationService {
  constructor() {}

  // going to accept ID as string to account for ID starting with 0
  public isValid(id: string): boolean {
    if (this.tryParseInt(id) === null) {
      return false;
    }

    const idArray = this.toNumberArray(id);
    if (idArray.length !== 13) {
      return false;
    }

    if (!this.isValidDOB(id)) {
      return false;
    }

    return this.validateId(idArray);
  }

  private isValidDOB(id: string): boolean {
    const month = this.tryParseInt(id.substring(2, 4));
    const day = this.tryParseInt(id.substring(4, 6));

    // Validate month and day
    if (
      month < 1 ||
      month > 12 ||
      month == null ||
      day < 1 ||
      day > 31 ||
      day == null
    ) {
      return false;
    }

    //  Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov must not have more than 30 days
    if (
      (month === 4 || month === 6 || month === 9 || month === 11) &&
      day > 30
    ) {
      return false;
    }

    // Feb must not have more than 29 days
    if (month === 2 && day > 29) {
      return false;
    }

    // If Feb and day is 29, make sure is leap year
    if (month === 2 && day === 29) {
      let year = this.tryParseInt(id.substring(0, 2));
      const currentYearTwoDigit = new Date().getFullYear() % 100;
      year += year > currentYearTwoDigit ? 1900 : 2000;

      // Check if is leap year
      if (year % 400 === 0 || (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0)) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  private toNumberArray(id: string): number[] {
    return id.split('').map((num) => Number(num));
  }

  private tryParseInt(value: string, defaultValue = null): number {
    const parsedValue = parseInt(value, 10);

    if (isNaN(parsedValue)) {
      return defaultValue;
    }
    return parsedValue;
  }

  private validateId(idArray: number[]): boolean {
    // get check digit (last digit of id)
    const checkDigit = idArray[12];
    // get list of odd values except check digit
    const oddValueArray = this.getOddValueArray(idArray);
    // add odd values together
    const oddValueSum = this.getSumOfNumberArray(oddValueArray);
    // get list of even values
    const evenValueArray = this.getEvenValueArray(idArray);
    // concat even values into one number
    let concatedEvenValues = this.concatNumberArray(evenValueArray);
    // multiple concated even numbers value by 2
    concatedEvenValues = concatedEvenValues * 2;
    // get list of values in new concated even number's value
    const concatedEvenValuesArray = this.toNumberArray(
      String(concatedEvenValues)
    );
    // add list of concated even number values together
    const sumOfConcatedEvenValues = this.getSumOfNumberArray(
      concatedEvenValuesArray
    );
    // add odd value sum and concated even number sum together
    const sumofOddAndEven = oddValueSum + sumOfConcatedEvenValues;
    // convert the above sum into a list of values
    const sumOfOddAndEvenArray = this.toNumberArray(String(sumofOddAndEven));
    // get last digit of above value
    const lastDigit = sumOfOddAndEvenArray[sumOfOddAndEvenArray.length - 1];
    // get verifyCheckDigit which is 10 minus the above last digit
    // (I am using %10 to ensure that 10-0 = 0, because if 10-0 = 10 compare digits will return false)
    let verifyCheckDigit = (10 - lastDigit) % 10;
    // if verifyCheckDigit has two digits, get the last digit
    if (verifyCheckDigit > 9) {
      verifyCheckDigit = this.toNumberArray(String(verifyCheckDigit)).pop();
    }
    // compare check digits and return true or false
    return this.compareCheckDigits(checkDigit, verifyCheckDigit);
  }

  private getSumOfNumberArray(numberArray: number[]): number {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
      sum = sum + numberArray[i];
    }
    return sum;
  }

  private getOddValueArray(idArray: number[]): number[] {
    const oddArray = [];
    oddArray.push(idArray[0]);
    oddArray.push(idArray[2]);
    oddArray.push(idArray[4]);
    oddArray.push(idArray[6]);
    oddArray.push(idArray[8]);
    oddArray.push(idArray[10]);
    return oddArray;
  }

  private getEvenValueArray(idArray: number[]): number[] {
    const evenArray = [];
    evenArray.push(idArray[1]);
    evenArray.push(idArray[3]);
    evenArray.push(idArray[5]);
    evenArray.push(idArray[7]);
    evenArray.push(idArray[9]);
    evenArray.push(idArray[11]);
    return evenArray;
  }

  private concatNumberArray(numberArray: number[]): number {
    return Number(numberArray.join(''));
  }

  private compareCheckDigits(
    checkDigit: number,
    verifyCheckDigit: number
  ): boolean {
    if (verifyCheckDigit === checkDigit) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```